# I have mysql 5.7 file, I get this error when I try to import it in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, import, migration

Here is the code where I get error. I removed the  NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION from the setmode as it was giving error before.

```
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_Insert_Asset_class_data_1000` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_Insert_Asset_class_data_1000'()
BEGIN
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuZN5.png)

Comment: Lost connection error in most cases means that the time needed for the script execution is greater that the timeout which is set in the client settings. Try to execute the command shown in the Import progress window in CMD. Also check the `@@max_packet_size` server setting.

Comment: @Akina actually this code is from sql file database which is exported from mysql 5.7  version sql dump file and my lead asked me to import that database in 8.0 and i managed to resolve as many errors as I can manually but the lead asked me too find a way to do this by any utility or any other way to make this database  compatible with 8.0 as we cant afford to resolve each issue manually and its time consuming.